# Scan if al matches have been made in a memorie game

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, variables

I made a memorie game with 6 cars (3 matches). I want to make something that is all 3 matches are made that you hear a win sound (`win.play()`). So i need an if statment that scans if all 3 matches are made and then plays the audio. But i don't know how to scan if the matches are made.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;
  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 1200);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));

// if ..... {
//   win.play();
// }
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url("img/achtergrond.png");
}

.memory-game {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(33% - 10px);
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #DFD7CB;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="memory-game">

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ember">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/banaan.png" alt="banaan" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ember">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/banaan.png" alt="banaan" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="backbone">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/bril.png" alt="bril" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="backbone">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/bril.png" alt="bril" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="react">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/vogel.png" alt="vogel" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="react">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/vogel.png" alt="vogel" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <audio id="win" src="media/win.wav"></audio>

</body>
```

So i need something (an if statment) that if alle 3 matches are made the win sound `win.play()` plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a variable `allMatched` and increment its value whenever a match is found. Then in the resetBoard function, you can check for a condition whether the `allMatched` is equal to half of the card's length and then run the audio.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let allMatched = 0;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;
  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  allMatched++;
  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 1200);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
  
  if (allMatched == cards.length/2) {
    win.play();
  }
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url("img/achtergrond.png");
}

.memory-game {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(33% - 10px);
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #DFD7CB;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="memory-game">

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ember">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/banaan.png" alt="banaan" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="ember">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/banaan.png" alt="banaan" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="backbone">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/bril.png" alt="bril" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="backbone">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/bril.png" alt="bril" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="react">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/vogel.png" alt="vogel" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="react">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/vogel.png" alt="vogel" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/vraagteken.png" alt="?" />
    </div>
  </section>

  <audio id="win" src="media/win.wav"></audio>
```